# Creating a user input array in MIPS

Tags: mips

I have to use this C++ coding and mimic it:
In my class we just learned about loops and arrays. Im confused about what I am doing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bQIH.png

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Post the code itself directly in your question. In any case, the answer to your question is that it depends on your target environment. For example, if you're using a simulator like SPIM or MARS then read the system call documentation for that simulator.

Comment: We are using Spim. I understand how to do a good chunk of this program what i really need is and better understanding arrays. I know I should create a label for each input and input. What I'm not fully understanding is how to connect it to the array. So if you could help me with understanding arrays better I would greatly appreciate that